# How to handle both encoded and decoded URI In node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, router

I want to handle both an encoded or plain URI in node.js. Is there an express middleware which routes after decoding the url.

for example:

how to handle

```
http://example.com/api/get/test%3Flimit=10%26filter=test
```

and

```
http://example.com/api/get/test?limit=10&filter=test
```

both the above routes in my express app.

I am using express 4.0.

Comment: Have you tried `encodeURI()`?

Comment: do you mean app.use(encodeURI()) ??

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: i am developing an express app and my requests for http://example.com/api/get/test%3Flimit=10%26filter=test, which is an encoded uri is failing as its not able to find that route .

Comment: Express handles decoding properly encoding URLs for you automatically.  What problem are you actually to trying to solve?  If someone is sending you URLs like the first one you show and you're expecting to handle it like the second one, then that's a bad client that should not be encoding the whole URL that way.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes thats exactly whats happening, app is sending URL like the first one , so URL shouldn't be encoded? i mean can't express handle both?

Comment: The client is screwing up.  You should fix the client.  You don't encode a `?` that you intend to be interpreted as the start of the query string and you don't encode an `&` that is supposed to be interpreted as a separator in the query string.  The client is just screwing up and there's no proper way for you to handle a legal URL and also decode stuff that isn't supposed to be encoded.  You'd have no way of telling which was which.  Fix the client.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the response, client is not mine. but i will ask the client developer to handle it. but just wanted to know if handle both is possible.

Comment: The client is improperly encoding their URL.  They are likelly encoding the whole URI using a function meant only for a component of the URL which gives an improperly encoded URL.  Hopefully you can explain this to the developer.  If not, then you may need to dig out some URL encoding specs or articles on proper encoding and pass them to the client developer.